# Using Pandas Dataframe and Dict to write a python function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

Parsing data into a tsv file using pandas dataframe and dict

```
def write_tsv(file, tsv):
    tsv.write(str(file['lp']) + '\t')
    tsv.write('\t')
```

The function should look like

```
def write_sample(file: dict,  header) -> pd.DataFrame:
```

Comment: Please, provide more detail on what your problem is and what you have tried. It is also unclear why you have a function called `write_tsv` that returns a `pd.DataFrame`. I would expect that from a function that **reads** a TSV.

Comment: I have edited it, it needs to be a function that parses a file and returns  a dataframe

Comment: If it's parsing a file and returning a dataframe, that's a _read_ function, not a "write" function.  This function with parameter `sep="\t"` should do it: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html

Comment: So it is a function that **reads** a TSV, correct?

Comment: The title "Using Pandas Dataframe and Dict to write a python function" sounds like you're trying to do automatic code generation based on a dataframe.... and why is the "file" parameter a dict?

Answer (score 0):

if I understand correctly , you don't need to write a custom function to to write tsv files using pandas , instead use `to_csv` file and pass tab as seperator:

```
df.to_csv(path, sep='\t')

# or if you want to read from tsv file into a dataframe :

df = pd.read_csv(path , sep='\t')
```